# Autocomplete Unavailable error when viewing Reputation tab

Tags: bug, status-declined, profile-page, reputation-graph, error-message

I just started having this problem today, but when I am in Stack Overflow and I click on the Reputation tab, I get a popup stating that Autocomplete is unavailable.  More specifically, an exception error and I was wondering if this is a bug or if it is something I did.

[image: Jquery popup stating that Autocomplete is unavailable]

> The following are some of the specs to help recreate this bug

Browser- Google Chrome  11.0.696.71 (Official Build 86024)
OS - Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium Edition Service Pack 1 (build 7601), 64-bit

> Update:The issue has been determined to be a problem with the jsshell extension, which I have enabled.  Will disable it now.

Comment: A *popup*? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: It wouldn't let me post it yet because I just joined meta stack overflow today and needed higher reputation.  I will try again now.

Comment: @balpha, posted screenie.

Comment: For what it is worth, using the same Chrome build, Windows 7 Pro 64bit with SP1, nothing like that seems to appear no matter what crazy clicking and refreshes that I do...

Comment: have you 'cleared-your-cache-type' refreshed the page?

Comment: Yes I have, it appears every time.

Comment: Yes I have, it appears every time.  I can give a list of extensions that are installed, that may be of some assistance.

Here is a list, maybe they are conflicting with the browser and site 

http://checkvist.com/checklists/72301-chrome-extensions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It [appears to be a known issue](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&p=38263) when using Chrome, HighCharts (which does the reputation chart), and a [specific Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/kmgmkbicahmbceidoidjbkbpkfogaldh?hl=sv). It appears as if the only solution for now is to uninstall that extension. (It may potentially occur with any extension that impacts Javascript, so you may have to disable them one-by-one to isolate which one it is if you don't have that one).

The person in the above thread who reported the issue linked to a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833883/weird-chrome-prototype-jquery-conflict) (dogfeeding!), but he didn't seem to find the answers satisfactory (and I'm not sure how relevant this is).

Comment: I do have jsshell and I will disable it now, thanks for the research and I am not sure what dogfeeding means, but I was not trying to do that at all.

Comment: @Jon waiwai means "dogfooding"; that's a programming term meaning "not only creating, but also using your own software". He referred to finding the reason for your SO problem by using SO.

Comment: Oh, okay, I guess I understand now.  Thanks for the clarification.  Anyway, the issue on my end is fixed now.

Comment: thanks for the solution, in my case the problem was with the extension jsshell 3.1